# Android source code attached: wrong line number when trace into View class

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app using eclipse. I've chosen the 14 Project build target and attached the SDK sources (The same version, 14). When I debug my project and try to trace into View class, the debugger shows a wrong line: it should show the first line of layout method (line 11170) but it traces comment lines (line 11395).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? If this isn't  the right way to attach core sources, how can I do that?

Comment: Unless you are using an officiall vanilla android build (emulator perhaps?) it would be no surprise if the actual code on your device were slightly or even substantially different than the upstream sources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd thought it should have worked properly because I'd tried to debug the app in my xperia arc with 4.0.1 installed and I'd attached 4.0.1 sources version. But you are right, I've tried with the emulator and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Things that help me when there's out of sync line numbers in eclipse;

- Close the activity
- Clean the project
- Rebuild the project
- Reopen the activity

Especially when sharing files between users in eclipse, whether using SVN software or live project sharing plugins, this is a very persistent annoyance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It could help me in the future, but the problem matches Chris' reply.